# Meaning of the symbol ꓡꓶ

Tags: notation

I came across this expression in an algorithm that I am working on.
p=M/2*pi
m=ꓡpꓶ
Could anyone help me with what this symbol means 'ꓡꓶ'?
Thank you.

Comment: Would you please cite where you "came across this expression in an algorithm"?  It certainly looks like the nearest integer function, but context is everything in getting the notation right.

Answer (score 3):

Usually $\lfloor x \rfloor$ denotes the floor function of $x$ and $\lceil x \rceil$ the ceiling function. So $\lfloor x \rceil$ probably means that you take the closest integer to $x$.

If this is correct, $\lfloor 1.45 \rceil = 1$ and $\lfloor 1.55 \rceil = 2$ and the case $\lfloor 1.5 \rceil$ depends on the convention.